# How to Automatic Record deployment with Java Agent in New Relic?

Tags: java, deployment, newrelic

How Can i **record deployment with Java Agent** or other alternatives **automatically**?

As from the [New Relic Documentation](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/agents/java-agent/instrumentation/recording-deployments-java-agent) we manually had to execute the Java agent jar from command line to send deployment information to New Relic.

```
java -jar newrelic.jar deployment [options]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How you will do this depends on what method you are currently using to deploy. You will need to figure out how to trigger that command or the appropriate [API Call](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/apm/new-relic-apm/maintenance/setting-deployment-notifications) during your deployment process. If you need further assistance please reach out to us at support.newrelic.com